# Export and import all module and userform (not access to VbaProject.OTM)

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a code to import and export all modules and `userform` from Excel, but I need that to works on Outlook.

I can not share file `VbaProject.OTM` with my code (citrix not sync this file and Outlook profile is virtual from citrix a cant see).

For the moment the solution is to export and import each module and `userform` manually, but with Excel I can import and export with `vba` code,

How do I import and export from Outlook?

```
    Public Sub ExportModules()

   szExportPath = "M:\ICM\Downloads\excel_test\"

    On Error Resume Next
        Kill szExportPath & "*.*"
    On Error GoTo 0

    szSourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    Set wkbSource = Application.Workbooks(szSourceWorkbook)

    For Each cmpComponent In wkbSource.VBProject.VBComponents

        bExport = True

        szFileName = cmpComponent.Name

        ct = cmpComponent.Type

        Select Case ct

            Case 3
                szFileName = szFileName & ".frm"

            Case 1
                szFileName = szFileName & ".bas"

            Case Else
                bExport = False

        End Select

        If bExport Then
            cmpComponent.Export szExportPath & szFileName
        End If

    Next cmpComponent

    MsgBox "Esportazione completata"

End Sub
```

and code to import modules and userform from excel:

```
Public Sub ImportModules()

    delmodules = True

    If ActiveWorkbook.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then delmodules = False

    szTargetWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    Set wkbTarget = Application.Workbooks(szTargetWorkbook)

    szImportPath  = "M:\ICM\Downloads\excel_test\"

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If objFSO.GetFolder(szImportPath).Files.Count = 0 Then
       MsgBox "Nessun file da importare"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    Call DeleteVBAModulesAndUserForms(delmodules)

    Set cmpComponents = wkbTarget.VBProject.VBComponents

    For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(szImportPath).Files
        If (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "frm") Or _
           (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "bas") Then
           cmpComponents.Import objFile.Path
        End If

    Next objFile

    MsgBox "Importazione completata"

End Sub

Function DeleteVBAModulesAndUserForms(delmodules)

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

    For Each VBComp In VBProj.VBComponents
        If VBComp.Type = 1 Or VBComp.Type = 3 Then
           'Thisworkbook or worksheet module
           'We do nothing
        Else
           VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
        End If

        Next VBComp

End Function
```

but for the moment function DeleteVBAModulesAndUserForms does not work very well, because add each module imported and not rewrite.

but first my goal is code to work in Outlook.

I'm test to create a `CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` but then I don't know how to set in outlook 
 `ActiveWorkbook.Name` and `Application.Workbooks`.

if anyone knows please help me.

Comment: VBIDE object isn't exposed in the Outlook VBA object for security due to Outlook connected to the internet,  allowing programmatic access to the VBIDE object could be a major exploit-

Comment: thanks @0m3r for answer, yes, i export and import modules and userform manually, every time i edit files. To share each modules to my colleagues first export my modules, then import modules on each outlook app colleagues. So for security reason i can not use code vba VBProject.VBComponents.Import or Export do it automatically as opposed to excel.?

Comment: hello, i'm resolved with ms access,  create a mask with button's with email code and share file ms access for each user. thansk.